# Code razor within Javascript code

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

The code below does not work.

I've tried all forms

`@:`
`@()`
`@{}`
`<text> </text>`

The apparent problem is the `{` and `}` at the beginning and end. (Required, as are parameters)

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function initializeFileUploader()
    {
        SetUploader('/Projects/ImageUpload', 'Images', true, ['jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif', 'zip'], { ProjectID: @Model.ID } );
        SetUploader('/Projects/ImageUpload', 'Logo', false, ['jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif'], { Logo: true, ProjectID: "@(Model.ID)" } );
    }
    window.onload = initializeFileUploader;

</script>
```

How to use, `@Model.ID` in my JavaScript?

## [Edit] Adding info

### With this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function initializeFileUploader()
    {
        SetUploader('/Projects/ImageUpload', 'Images', true, ['jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif', 'zip'], { ProjectID: @HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(Model.ID.ToString(), true) });
        SetUploader('/Projects/ImageUpload', 'Logo', false, ['jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif'], { Logo: true, ProjectID: @HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(Model.ID.ToString(), true) } );
    }

    window.onload = initializeFileUploader();

</script>
```

### The razor generate this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        function initializeFileUploader()
        {
            SetUploader('/Projects/ImageUpload', 'Images', true, ['jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif', 'zip'], { ProjectID: &quot;860c13af-9aa9-4667-8ee8-c5629515c71b&quot; 

</body>
</html>
```

### **[Add]** Another example of code

```
$('#Logo').bindAjaxUploader({
    action: '/Project/ImageUpload',
    allowedExtensions:  ['jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif'],
    params: { Logo: true, ProjectID: @HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(Model.ID.ToString(), true) }
});
```

If you set the value manually, **everything works perfectly!**

```
$('#Logo').bindAjaxUploader({
    action: '/Project/ImageUpload',
    allowedExtensions:  ['jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif'],
    params: { Logo: true, ProjectID: "559b0505-09f2-4385-aee0-530d79c82803" }
});
```

## [Edit] Resolution

**To correct the problem, I had to do this: (not an elegant way)**

```
@{
    @:function initializeFileUploader()
    @:{
            @:SetUploader('/Projects/ImageUpload', 'Images', true, ['jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif', 'zip'], { ProjectID: "@(HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(Model.ID.ToString()))" });
            @:SetUploader('/Projects/ImageUpload', 'Logo', false, ['jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif'], { Logo: true, ProjectID: "@(HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(Model.ID.ToString()))" });
        @:}

    @:window.onload = initializeFileUploader;
}
```

Comment: Define "does not work". What is it supposed to do? What does it do? What error messages do you get (if any)?

Comment: That should work fine.  What do you see in the rendered source?  Is `Model.ID` a string?

Comment: `Model.ID` and the object ID. When generate the HTML should look something like:

`SetUploader('/Projects/ImageUpload', 'Images', true, ['jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif', 'zip'], { ProjectID: "123456"} );`


Note the value of `ProjectID`, it is dynamic. Should get the `Model.ID.`

For me not works! The HTML generated is wrong, see the Javascript code that generates this code. It does not generate the complete HTML, just to 'ProjectID: 123456' And there!. The rest of the JavaScript is not generated.

Comment: **You have a sytnax issue in the surrounding code**.  Please show a complete file that demonstrates this problem.

Comment: Put all the details (including the complete code) this link:   https://gist.github.com/1371965

Comment: I'm doing a test, even a simple function, passing the value Model.ID as I can. See:

`uploader("@HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(Model.ID.ToString(), false)");`

This code does not work for me. Try it too.

Comment: @RidermandeSousaBarbosa: I just tried your sample; it works fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

```
window.onload = initializeFileUploader();
```

This is executing initializeFileUploader() straight away, BEFORE window.onload is actually called, it should be

```
window.onload = initializeFileUploader;
```

Comment: See my changes in the question please.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting @Model.ID in single quotes '@Model.ID'. This always works for me.

Here is the code:

```
function initializeFileUploader()
{
    SetUploader('/Projects/ImageUpload', 'Images', true, ['jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif', 'zip'], { ProjectID: '@Model.ID' });
    SetUploader('/Projects/ImageUpload', 'Logo', false, ['jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif'], { Logo: true, ProjectID: '@Model.ID' });
}

window.onload = initializeFileUploader;
```

Comment: I do not know why, but it does not work for me!
This was what the 'razor' generated:  http://i.imgur.com/CYx9W.png   This is the end of the HTML code:  <script type="text/javascript">

        

    `function initializeFileUploader()
    {

        SetUploader('/Projects/ImageUpload', 'Images', true, ['jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif', 'zip'], { ProjectID: 'ad9bc1d0-ab0b-45a9-8fe8-f7fb79146abb', true) 

</body>
</html>`

Comment: I see that the ID is interpreted as it should. Have you tried hardcoding a value to see if it will render successfully? It would also be helpful if you can provide us with the whole markup of the view.

Comment: Hello, I modified my function. I created a jQuery plugin to encapsulate everything.

**Was as follows:**

`$('#Logo').bindAjaxUploader({
  action: '/Project/ImageUpload',
  allowedExtensions:  ['jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif'],
  params: { Logo: true, ProjectID: "559b0505-09f2-4385-aee0-530d79c82803" }
 });`

As you can see I put the ID value in the parameter `ProjectID`

Comment: `$('#Logo').bindAjaxUploader({
 action: '/Project/ImageUpload',
 allowedExtensions:  ['jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif'],
 params: { Logo: true, ProjectID: @HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(Model.ID.ToString(), true) }
});`

The same function, but with the dynamic value, does not work! Razor just does not generate the HTML code from `ProjectID: `

Comment: I noticed I had an error in my code above. Please try again. I have edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Both of your code samples should work fine.

My psychic powers tell me that `Model.ID` is a string, so you end up writing the string value to the Javascript without quotes.  Therefore, it gets parsed as a variable name rather than a value.
Instead, call `@HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(Model.ID, true)` to output a properly-escaped string literal.

Comment: user551841's answer is correct; I missed that.  This might be a separate problem.

Comment: See my changes in the question please.

Comment: Sorry; I forgot to add that you need `Html.Raw` to prevent it from HTML-escaping the Javascript.  You may want to wrap all that in your own extension method.

Comment: It looks like you have a syntax error in your surrounding HTML that is causing Razor to think it's in code context.  Look for unmatched tags and stray `@`s.

Comment: Would you post an example?

**I tried as follows:**

`function initializeFileUploader()
{
 SetUploader('/Projects/ImageUpload', 'Images', true, ['jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif', 'zip'], { ProjectID: @Html.Raw(HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(Model.ID.ToString(), true)) });
 SetUploader('/Projects/ImageUpload', 'Logo', false, ['jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif'], { Logo: true, ProjectID: @Html.Raw(HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(Model.ID.ToString(), true)) } );
}`

Comment: **Results**

`function initializeFileUploader()
{
 SetUploader('/Projects/ImageUpload', 'Images', true, ['jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif', 'zip'], { ProjectID: "54432102-e9c1-47d7-8b2f-449d0633bb65" `

Comment: You now have the output correct.  The early termination is a separate issue that is probably caused by a surrounding syntax error, as I just said.

Comment: The output is not correct!
The rest of the javascript is not being generated.
Where is the error. See the edition (Resolution). Not the way I like.

Comment: As I said, you have misbalanced tags or braces somewhere.  You don't need all that.  (at the very least, you can replace all that with a single `<text>` tag.